# jasper ireport primeiro registro

Tags: jasper-reports

Meu relatorio em Jasper ireport so exibe o primerio registro

**Codigo**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.4.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_Letter" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c48467be-87c9-4ccb-90b9-fcfa33a9d84f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value="YmFuY290ZXN0ZS5jbGllbnRlICwxNSwxNSxlNTU0NDA1OS0xYzI5LTQwMzAtYjVkNC03YTFiYjUzNjMxMWY7"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mysqlxampp"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM bancoteste.cliente]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="nome" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="idade" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="codigo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="230" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="d12daa5e-ea80-4790-8af5-25c99f14b6db"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[RELATORIO]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="356" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="6649fe5c-d657-4d3d-b672-2f44fc082ea3"/>
                <text><![CDATA[codigo]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="9fef867a-3cbe-4c85-9d4e-daee2441b491"/>
                <text><![CDATA[nome]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4be07db8-dd06-4db7-9dae-f2b5712167de"/>
                <text><![CDATA[idade]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="356" y="20" width="100" height="19" uuid="237beee7-de42-446c-b966-26d53164f46a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{codigo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="100" height="19" uuid="487128c2-8ed2-4e64-ad5f-d03e7cf8c5ce"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nome}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="180" y="20" width="100" height="19" uuid="5a4e7139-82d7-462a-b121-466dc8ac0e3c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idade}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro está ocorrendo porque você colocou seus campos na seção "Cabeçalho", o correto é coloca-las em "Detail". Você move os títulos das colunas para a column header, ou seja seus Static Texts e os textFields ficam na parte de detail logo abaixo dos títulos.

Isso da um relatório assim:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                      Relatório  (Pg1)                   |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
|  Coluna 1 | Coluna 2 | Coluna 3 |       Column Header   |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| TextField |TextField |TextField |                       |
| TextField |TextField |TextField |       Detail          |
| TextField |TextField |TextField |                       |

.... Pg 2

+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
|  Coluna 1 | Coluna 2 | Coluna 3 |       Column Header   |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| TextField |TextField |TextField |                       |
| TextField |TextField |TextField |       Detail          |
| TextField |TextField |TextField |                       |
```

Ou você pode desejar que os textos estáticos sejam uma espécie de legenda para os dados, então faria assim

```
+----------------------------------------------+----------+
|                 Relatório (Title)            |          |
+----------------------------------------------+----------+
|  Nome: (Static Text) ZZZZZZ (TextField)      |          |
|  Endereço: (Static Text) ZZZZZZ (TextField)  |  Detail  |
```

Salvo engano a diferença entre essa seção ColumnHeader e a Title é que a primeira se repete em todas as páginas, já a Title só aparece na primeira página.